# Use Of Undeclared Identifier in my function

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm having a use of undeclared identifier even though that I declared it in the .h and synthesize in the .m.

I had another problem before, but I posted a question in stack overflow and they said that I shouldn't extern them and when I extered them the code gave me an error "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" and know I didn't and it's giving me "Use Of Undeclared Identifier" as you can see

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

BOOL OFrameIsHidden, XFrameIsHidden;
NSString *topOne, *topTwo, *topThree;
NSString *midOne, *midTwo, *midThree;
NSString *botOne, *botTwo, *botThree;

void hideAll(void);

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
void hideAll(void);
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *XFrame;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *OFrame;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *frame;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *X;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *O;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *WhoWon;



@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *oneOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *oneTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *oneThree;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *twoOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *twoTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *twoThree;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *threeOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *threeTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *threeThree;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize XFrame, OFrame, frame, X, O, WhoWon;
@synthesize oneOne, oneTwo, oneThree;
@synthesize twoOne, twoTwo, twoThree;
@synthesize threeOne, threeTwo, threeThree;

void hideAll(void){

    [OFrame setHidden:YES];
    [XFrame setHidden:YES];
    [frame setHidden:YES];

    [X setHidden:YES];
    [O setHidden:YES];


    [oneOne setHidden:YES];
    [oneTwo setHidden:YES];
    [oneThree setHidden:YES];

    [oneOne setHidden:YES];
    [twoTwo setHidden:YES];
    [twoThree setHidden:YES];

    [threeOne setHidden:YES];
    [threeTwo setHidden:YES];
    [threeThree setHidden:YES];
}
```

For your information there is some more code for the IBAcions, but I don't want to make this long.

Comment: and this is tagged C++ because...?

Comment: Which identifier is undeclared? What is the full error message? On which line does it occur? - How do you expect to get an answer without providing any of that information?

Comment: Use pure objective-c. Don't mix with C++. BTW, if you really want, change an extension of your ViewController from .m to .mm

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix functions and methods like this. It doesn't really help you and all you have done is create visibility issues.

Methods work by passing a hidden parameter which gives access to `self`. All of your `@property` definitions are instance variables, so you need access to `self` to get to them. Functions, like your `hideAll`, don't have this access so they can't get to the instance variables (they don't know what an instance is).

You generally also don't want variables defined outside the class definition.

Bring your variables into the class or move them to another more appropriate class and use methods for your code, not functions.